# Rails - Path is Routing to View but not seeing the path in Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I have inherited a rails app so don't know exactly how certain things were set up. My app was originally designed with a sign-up form but I have since removed that functionality. For some reason when I go to localhost:3000/users/sign_up it still loads that page. I'm looking at the routes file and not seeing anything in there related to that. I believe they used devise for the app is there somewhere else I should be looking? I would like to redirect any requests for users/sign_up to the root of the site.

Comment: Can you post your routes.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your app is using the default Devise routes. If you go to your routes.rb file, you should see a line like this:

```
devise_for :users
```

This means that Devise is generate a bunch of default routes for for you. If you were to type `rake routes` in your terminal, you'd see something similar to the following:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)     devise/sessions#new
```

This, and the other user routes like it, have been generated by Devise via the `devise_for :users` in your routes.rb file.

If you'd like to customize the default routing Devise has set up for you, you can find some useful information in the Devise documentation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-routes). They give you an example of how to change the /users/sign_in route like so:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get 'sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

Just change the `'devise/sessions#new'` to point to whichever controller action you'd like to use, say `'home#index'` if you're looking to have users sign in from the homepage.